# How to jump to a specific character in vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

How can I jump to the next character X in vim?

I frequently use, e.g., `dt:` or `ct:` to delete/change everything up until a colon (or some other character).

Is there any short key combo to simply move my cursor position to that character?

Comment: http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif

Comment: If only the top 2 partial answers had been one - and additionally contained this information:  the unmentioned`T` will jump to _after_ the first sought character to the left, and I can confirm that the `;` and `,` repeaters work with all of `f`/`F`/`t`/`T`.

Answer (score 399, accepted):

You can type `f<character>` to put the cursor on the next character and `F<character>` for the previous one.

Comment: You can also use `;` to repeat the operation and use `,` to repeat it in opposite direction.

Comment: This only seems to work with matches on the same line for me.

Comment: @JpajiRajnish Yes. Use `/<character>` to match it anywhere.

Comment: It seems that using f<character> (along with the ; and , characters for repeating the command) only works on the line the cursor is at. Is there a way to make it work across the entire file?

Comment: I would use search in this case; see comment above.

Comment: @Rsh You saved my life with `,`, sometimes I get overzealous and jump past and never knew I could go back.

Answer (score 79):

`t` and `f` work without a command as well, so to move to colon use `f:` and to move to right before colon use `t:`

Comment: Is there a way to move to right after the colon?

Comment: @james you can always move to the symbol after the colon using `fSYMBOL`, if you want to edit text after the colon you can use `f:a`

Answer (score 12):

If you do a search for that character with `/`, you can then hit `n` to move to the next occurrence of it.

Comment: I'm wondering how to undo this find once I've found the character. All matching characters seem to remain highlighted in the current buffer.

Comment: @newswim, :nohl

Comment: You can also just search for something else (e.g. a bunch of garbage that won't be matched) to change the highlighted search string.  There is also `:set invhls` which is useful for toggling the highlights off and on (I map this to a shortcut for quick toggling).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are just searching for a pure vim combination but EasyMotion is a plugin that worth trying. HTH. :)